# How to zoom out status bar when using launch image in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm developing app and using launch image.
So in iPhone6 or iPhone6 Plus status bar is zoomed.

I know we have to use launch screen to avoid that.
I think We have to use autolayout if we use launch screen.

But Is there no way we can zoom out status bar without using launch screen and autolayout?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean "zoom out status bar"?

Comment: @DuncanC I mean reduce status bar height. The same effect as launch screen.

Comment: You don't need to use a launch screen with the iPhone 6 or 6+. Only the iPad Pro requires a launch screen.

Comment: @rmaddy I know, But if we use launch image, the status bar will be zoomed in iPhone6 and iPhone6s Plus.

Comment: If you use the correct launch images it will not be zoomed.

Comment: @rmaddy no, not at all.

Comment: No, it won't be zoomed with the correct launch images. That's the whole point of using the proper launch images. It tells iOS that your app supports those screen sizes. Just make sure your iPhone isn't setup to be zoomed under Settings.

Comment: @rmaddy Maybe I think i don't set launch image correctly. Could you tell me how to set proper iPhone6s plus launch image? And How can I setup iphone to not be zoomed? I can't find option in settings.

Comment: Settings -> Display & Brightness ->  View. Pick Standard.

Comment: @rmaddy, When I use launch screen for iPhone6, it doesn't look good in iphone 4 and 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use launchscreen and autolayout.
Launch image is not recommended way.
With autolayout, status bar will not be zoomed